# Set line colors according to colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of lines stored in a list like so:

```
line_list = [line_1, line_2, line_3, ..., line_M]
```

where each `line_i` is a sub-list composed of two sub-sub-lists, one for the x coordinates and the other for the y coordinates:

```
line_i = [[x_1i, x2_i, .., x_Ni], [y_1i, y_2i, .., y_Ni]]
```

I also have a list of the same length as `line_list` composed of floats,:

```
floats_list = [0.23, 4.5, 1.6, ..., float_M]
```

I want to plot each line giving it a color taken from a color map and related to the position of its index in the `floats_list` list. So `line_j` will have its color determined by the number `floats_list[j]`. I also need a colorbar shown to the side

The code would like something like this, except it should work :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line1 = [[0.5,3.6,4.5],[1.2,2.0,3.6]]
line2 = [[1.5,0.4,3.1,4.9],[5.1,0.2,7.4,0.3]]
line3 = [[1.5,3.6],[8.4,2.3]]

line_list = [line1,line2,line3]
floats_list = [1.2,0.3,5.6]

# Define colormap.
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

# plot all lines.
for j,lin in enumerate(line_list): 
    plt.plot(lin[0], lin[1], c=floats_list[j])

# Show colorbar.
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easiest to use a `LineCollection` for this.  In fact, it expects the lines to be in a similar format to what you already have.   To color the lines by a third variable, just specify the `array=floats_list`.  As an example:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# The line format you curently have:
lines = [[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)],
         [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)],
         [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (8, 7, 6, 5, 4)],
         [(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)]]

# Reformat it to what `LineCollection` expects:
lines = [zip(x, y) for x, y in lines]

z = np.array([0.1, 9.4, 3.8, 2.0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = LineCollection(lines, array=z, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, linewidths=5)
ax.add_collection(lines)
fig.colorbar(lines)

# Manually adding artists doesn't rescale the plot, so we need to autoscale
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

[image]

There are two main advantages of this over repeatedly calling `plot`.

1. Rendering speed.  `Collections` render much faster than a large number of similar artists.
2. It's easier to color the data by another variable according to a colormap (and/or update the colormap later).

Comment: Joe, if I understand correctly the `Z` in your code is equivalent to my `floats_list`, but I'm not sure how the `x` and `y` arrays are related to my `line_list` list.

Comment: They're just data to generate what's already in your `line_list`.  The `lines` variable in the example is in exactly the same format as your `line_list`.

Comment: Woops, I misread the format you had slightly! Just a sec... (`LineCollection` expects a very similar format to what you already have, though.)

Comment: Excllent, but can we add legends to these lines?

Comment: Joe I've made a follow up question related to your answer (which is why @void is asking that I presume), if you have time please stop by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877666/add-legends-to-linecollection-plot

Comment: Yes @Gabrield, I'm asking here because you pointed out to this answer. It would be good to know if it's possible to add legends to a LineCollection.

Comment: Would be great to get `array` explained, like where it is comming from and what it is doing. Actually, it's the pivot point of the answer.